# bash use jq to get value if condition meets

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

I am trying to get certain value in the json with some for each and if condition.

code looks like the following

```
for i in "$(jq -r '.value[]' test.json)"; do
    result=$(echo $i | jq -r .result)
    if [ "$result" == "succeeded" ]
    then
      name=$(echo $i | jq -r .agent.name)
      echo "$name"
    fi
done
```

json file - test.json

```
{
   "count":3,
   "value":[
      {
         "location":"CA",
         "result":"failed",
         "agent":{
            "id":97833,
            "name":"Brad"
         },
         "priority":0
      },
      {
         "location":"TX",
         "result":"failed",
         "agent":{i
            "id":15232,
            "name":"Tom"
         },
         "priority":0
      },
      {
         "location":"CO",
         "result":"succeeded",
         "agent":{
            "id":13412,
            "name":"John"
         },
         "priority":0
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to loop through the json file using jq to get the name of the agent if the result was "succeeded". but the result i get from result=$(echo $i | jq -r .result) seems like it's returning string array @("failed","failed","succeeded").

========================update==============================

```
jq ' # get the name of the agent if the result was "succeeded".
  .value[]
  | select(.result == "succeeded")
  | var1=.agent.name
  | echo $var1
' test.json
```

if I want to save the .agent.name into a variable and use it with a different command, what do I have to do?

Comment: `for i in ...` doesn't have any idea how to iterate over JSON objects; it mostly iterates over "words", but in this case since the `$(jq ...) command substitution is double-quoted, it isn't split at all (it would be worse if it wasn't double-quoted, since every "{", "}", etc would be treated as a separate word). Also, you should almost always double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$i"` instead of `echo $i`) to avoid unexpected parsing weirdness. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Comment: In your code, the loop would be executed exactly once, with `i` set to the whole output of `jq`. The reason is that by using double-quotes, you tell the shell that you want to have the whole output as one piece. Without the double-quotes, the shell would perform word splitting on the output, and each iteration is done with one word of the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use a shell loop.

With your test.json,

```
jq ' # get the name of the agent if the result was "succeeded".
  .value[]
  | select(.result == "succeeded")
  | .agent.name
' test.json
```

produces:

```
"John"
```

Comment: To get output without the double-quotes, add the `-r` flag to `jq`. Note: do *not* try to iterate over the results with a `for` loop -- see [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: how can I save the output "John" to a variable so I can use that variable?

Comment: Your question seems to assume that there is only one name meeting the criterion.  If there is only one, then you could use the same technique as in your question, though it might be better to place the jq program in a file and invoke jq with the -f FILE option.  There are many other alternatives, though.